# replace cell values every 8 cells and then create another excel

Tags: python, pandas

I need my code to force excel to show 3 decimals every 8th row. The dataframe is an excel file with one column. When i run my code python  creates a file that is equal to the original one and i don't know why. Please help me!
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/feder/Desktop/DATA.xlsx")
row=6

    

while IndexError==True:
    value=df.iat[row,0]
    new_value="{:.2f}".format(float(value))
    print(new_value)
    df1=df.replace(value, new_value)
    row+=8


df1.to_excel("angelquirroz2.xlsx")
book= openpyxl.load_workbook("angelquirroz2.xlsx")
sheet=book["Sheet1"]
book.save("angelquirroz2.xlsx")
print("done")
```

Comment: The only difference is the formatting?

Comment: Could you provide example data so we can see what you mean?

Comment: yes the only difference is formatting. This is an example [link] (https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmPP2mb64sjYgeMn4aXkaX44LzwsOg?e=31LpE2)

Answer (score 1):

now i managed to write this loop, ma it takes more than 8 hours to modify 1000 files and i don't think i made it really efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import os
import xlsxwriter
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from os import path
import shutil
directory_path= r"C:\Users\..."
row=6
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith("CHANGED.xlsx"):
        continue
    if filename.endswith(".ipynb"):
        continue
    elif filename.endswith("checkpoints"):
        continue
    elif filename.endswith("spyproject"):
        continue
    else:
        workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        df=pd.read_excel(filename)
        lenght=len(df)
        row=6
        while row<=lenght:
            value=df.iat[row,0]      
            new_value=df.iat[row,0]="{:.3f}".format(float(value))
            row+=8
        #print(new_value)
        #print("done")
            file=filename.replace(".xlsx","")
            df.to_excel(""+file+"CHANGED.xlsx")    
  
print ("DONE!Now let's move the files in a new directory")  

directory_output=input("insert the directory path here: ")
dst= ""r""+directory_output+""
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith("CHANGED.xlsx"):         
        shutil.copy(path.join(directory_path, filename), dst)
    else:
        continue
```

thanks for the help